# Numerical value for inverse trig function on sympy

Tags: geometry, numeric

So, i am working with python and using Simpy, and i need to evaluate the Arc Cosine , but i can only get the expression, not the numerical value that i need.

```
line0.angle_between(ppline0)
line01.angle_between(ppline01)
line02.angle_between(ppline02)

def ang_lines(line0,line01,line02):
    if line0.angle_between(line01) == line0.angle_between(line02):
        return True
    else:
        return nsimplify(line0.angle_between(line01) - line0.angle_between(line02) , tolerance = 0.02)

line1.angle_between(ppline1)
line11.angle_between(ppline11)
line12.angle_between(ppline12)

ang_lines(line0,line01,line02)
```

I created a function that gives me the difference between the angles of two lines between a third one, but when i call the function, i only get the symbolic expression for it.

Comment: [Numerical Evaluation](https://docs.sympy.org/1.5.1/modules/evalf.html)